# Nouns, Counters, Adverbs of quantity

Tags: grammar

I was reading and I somehow got confused on what is the best way to say something like:

> She cooked 10 grams more of rice.

I have some ideas but I would like to know which one is the correct one.

In Japanese you go from the [Background information]>[Important information], that is what I read in a book, at least.
So:

> 米１０グラム大きく炊いた
>   米を１０グラム大きく炊いた
>   米を１０グラムで大きく炊いた
>   米１０グラムで大きく炊いた

I am not sure which one is the correct one, but could I have an explanation why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One natural way to say this would be

> 米を10グラム**多く**炊いた。

たくさん would be replaced with other adverbs such as たくさん, 余分に, 余計に, 多めに. But you would end up with a fairly awkward sentence if you used 大きく.

Aside from grammar, of course 10 grams of rice is too small a quantity; we usually say 200グラム, [1合](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C5%8D_(unit)), etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all 大きく炊いた is unnatural and 多く炊いた is natural.

米を１０グラム多く炊いた is natural. This を is used for the object.

米１０グラム多く炊いた is sometimes used. を is omitted here.

米を１０グラムで大きく炊いた and 米１０グラムで大きく炊いた are unnatural because the sentences don't need で.